# Access blocked: Authorization Error - The OAuth client was not found

Tags: django, oauth, google-oauth, google-api-python-client, django-socialauth

i'm working on a Django project and i want to implement the "Login via Google" functionality
i've created a new app and got its credentials (Client ID and Client Secret) and i've put them in my Django's project dashboard properly
but i'm getting this "Error 401: invalid_client" . i have added my client id and secrete key using the code below
SOCIAL_AUTH_GOOGLE_OAuth2_KEY='96637591302-7e0hla5amsv2hmibgi704ehd0v5n8dsl.apps.googleusercontent.com'

SOCIAL_AUTH_GOOGLE_OAuth2_SECERET='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'

thanks

i am trying to add login via a google functionality .but its giving an error 401 client-id not found